# Prober way to provide DB secrets to Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-postgres-exporter

I would like to use the [Prometheus PostgreSQL Exporter Helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus-postgres-exporter) to monitor the PostgreSQL DB.

However, I am concerned that, if I add the DB credentials as values for the Helm chart, such secrets can be seen in various configs or Kubernetes secrets.

Is there a secure way to do it?

Comment: Do you have a programming-related question, or is this more about deployment considerations?  Both Helm values and Kubernetes Secrets can be retrieved straightforwardly by someone with enough permissions in the cluster; you'd have to modify your application code to integrate with something like Vault if you wanted the credentials to not exist in Kubernetes space at all.

Comment: Sure, but can I combine vanilla Helm chart deployment and Vault secrets, somehow?